# Google Admob low payout per CPC

Tags: android, admob

I have installed AdMob in my game. And untill now I have 3 clicks on ads and my estimated balance is about 0.04€. I think that thos price is very low, do you think that 750 clicks on ads worth about 10€. Have I set everything OK?  Do you have similar experience with AdMob?

Comment: This is not really a programming question. However yes, You don't get much per click. On popular apps, ads may be more expensive per click, as it may show higher paid ads.

Comment: you cannot say anything about revenue so early on. so just wait a little bit unti you have more reliable data. Then ask again :)

Answer (score 1):

This question is not programming.
But I will try to help you. There is no such thing as a "cost per click in the application." It depends from the quarter, the economic situation, random garbage, user region...

https://www.quora.com/What-is-an-average-CPC-on-the-AdMob-network

If your application is popular in Africa, you will have a lower "cost per click".